# Limiting values from a broadcast statement

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I am sending a broadcast signal to find devices connected to the network. I need to limit the results to be unique. I use the statement below, but I still get repeats.

```
ping 192.168.100.255 -b | grep "200" -m 10 | cut -d : -f 1 | uniq | sort
```

Comment: first sort and then uniq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    rm /tmp/test.txt;touch /tmp/test.txt
    ping 192.168.100.255 -b |while read line;do
            line=`echo $line| grep "200" -m 10 | cut -d : -f 1 `;
            grep -Fxq "$line" /tmp/test.txt || (echo  $line|tee -a /tmp/test.txt);
    done
```